# read pdf file from specific byte to end of a file

Tags: python, pdf, offset

I use the code below to read from the beginning of the file to byte 89, but how can I read from byte 89 to the end of the file?

```
with open('hello-world.pdf','rb') as input_data:
    ima = input_data.read(89)
    print ima
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask, "How can I read the rest of the file after having read the first 89 bytes?" or, "How can I open a new file and read only  the bytes after byte #89?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) file operation sets the file's current position.

```
with open('hello-world.pdf','rb') as input_data:
    input_data.seek(89)      # Move to byte #89, i.e. skip first 89 bytes
    ima = input_data.read()  # Read all bytes from 89 to end of file
    print ima
```

Answer (score 2):

you can access byte 89 to end with this simple code just use `list` for access it:

```
with open('hello-world.pdf','rb') as input_data:
    ima = list(input_data.read())
    print ima[89:]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
aFH = open( 'hello-world.pdf', 'rb' )              # .GET aFileHANDLE
aFH.seek( 89, 0 )                                  # .MOV aReadPOINTER
ima = aFH.read( ... )                              # .GET ...
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your questions. Are you upset that I suggested that you include a link to the relevant documentation? (By the way, the -1 wasn't from me.)